# Fix the height/length of a minipage

Tags: beamer, framed, minipage, overlays, tabbing

I have 2 `columns` in 1 slide. On the left hand, it is a `tabbing` inside a  `minipage` in a `framed`. Some sentences are shown one by one by `overlay`, that results in the height/length of the whole minipage on the left increases gradually. I would like to fix the height/length in the beginning, and leave the place for the sentences coming up. Does anyone know how to do it?

```
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}
  \begin{framed}
    \resizebox{0.85\textwidth}{!}{%
      \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \begin{tabbing}
          \quad \= \hspace{-0.3cm} \quad \= \hspace{-0.1cm} \quad \= \hspace{-0.1cm} \quad \= \hspace{-0.1cm} \quad \= \hspace{0cm} \= \\[-\baselineskip]\kill
          ...
          \only<2->{sentence 2} \\
          \only<3->{sentence 3} \\
          \only<4->{sentence 4} 
        \end{tabbing}
      \end{minipage}}
  \end{framed}
\end{column}
\begin{column}
...
\end{column}
\end{columns}
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
  \begin{minipage}[t][10cm][t]{\textwidth}
```

will make a top aligned minipage that is 10cm tall.

Comment: Thank you... What I notice is that, the height is more or less fixed... I mean, showing the sentences one by one seems changing slightly the height and the font size... It is very odd...

Comment: edit the question to be a full document with \documentclass etc demonstrating the problem, and someone could test....

Comment: Actually I realize that replacing `\only` by `\onslide` solves the problem...