# mdframed box of fixed minimum height

Tags: spacing, boxes, mdframed

I would like my `mdframed` boxes from `MyEnvironment` to have a minimum total (title+body) height.  The height can be greater (if the content warrants it), but not smaller than a certain size.

I can probably hack up a solution by

1. Typesetting the `mdframed` into a `\savebox`,
2. Measuring it, and
3. Re-typsetting it with an appropriate `\vspace` inserted,

but wondering if there is a less hackish way to accomplish this.

The MWE produces the following, but the desired output would have blank space after the content body so that the height is the value set in `\MinimumHeight`.

[image]

Since the last box height is already greater than `\MinimumHeight` is should not be changed.

### Notes:

- The minimum height is a fixed constant known before compile time.

### References:

- This seems related: [Fix the height/length of a minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67284/fix-the-height-length-of-a-minipage), but not quite what I desire.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*{\MinimumHeight}{5.0cm}%

\NewEnviron{MyEnvironment}[1][]{%
    \begin{mdframed}[
        frametitlebackgroundcolor=brown!25,
        frametitlerulecolor=blue,
        frametitlerulewidth=1.0pt,
        backgroundcolor=yellow!25,
        #1
    ]
    \BODY
    \end{mdframed}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{MyEnvironment}[frametitle={Short Title}]
    Some text for first paragraph.

    Some more text for other paragraphs.
\end{MyEnvironment}

\begin{MyEnvironment}[frametitle={Some much longer title that takes up more than one line in the title frame}]
    Some text for first paragraph.
\end{MyEnvironment}


\begin{MyEnvironment}[frametitle={Title of frame with much text}]
    \lipsum[1]
\end{MyEnvironment}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

REVISED to account for height of title, and space from `\fboxsep` like things.

While not relevant to the solution presented, but only to your MWE, the use of the newly created `\singlelipsum` command is to avoid the `\par` that otherwise accompanies the end of a `\lipsum`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\singlelipsum[1]{%
  \begingroup\let\lips@par\relax\csname lipsum@\@roman{#1}\endcsname
\endgroup }
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\MinimumHeight}{3cm}%
\def\dH{18pt}

\newcommand\headerheight[1]{\heightof{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\strut#1\strut}}}

\NewEnviron{MyEnvironment}[1][]{%
    \begin{mdframed}[
        frametitlebackgroundcolor=brown!25,
        frametitlerulecolor=blue,
        frametitlerulewidth=1.0pt,
        backgroundcolor=yellow!25,
        #1
    ]
  \tabcolsep=0pt\relax
  \begin{tabular}{cp{\textwidth}}\mystrut{#1}&
    \BODY
  \end{tabular}
    \end{mdframed}
}
\def\mystrut#1{\rule[\heightof{\strutbox}-\MinimumHeight+\headerheight{#1}+\dH]{0ex}
  {\MinimumHeight-\headerheight{#1}-\dH}}

\begin{document}
\noindent\rule{\MinimumHeight}{.1ex} This is the MinimumHeight (sideways)
\begin{MyEnvironment}[frametitle={Short Title}]
    Some text for first paragraph.

    Some more text for other paragraphs.
\end{MyEnvironment}

\begin{MyEnvironment}[frametitle={Some much longer title that takes up more than one line in the title frame}]
    Some text for first paragraph.
\end{MyEnvironment}


\begin{MyEnvironment}[frametitle={Title of frame with much text}]
    \singlelipsum{1}
\end{MyEnvironment}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting solution -- much more elegant than what I had in mind. However, not sure I like putting everything in a `tabular` (or even a `minipage`). One problem with this current solution is that it has changed the paragraph indentation -- see how the text changes in the first example in your MWE if you comment out the `\begin{tabular}` and `\end{tabular}`. Now each of these issues can be adjusted but I don't know if there are other issues lurking that will need correction in the future.  Perhaps I am just being too paranoid.

Comment: @PeterGrill  Well, I haven't solved the indent thing, but indeed other issues lurked.  I just fixed one, in that one needed to account for `\fboxsep` like lengths that make the box bigger than the text itself.  I now placed a `\rule` at the top of the page to realize I needed 18pt worth of adjustment to the MinimumHeight.

Comment: 18pt?  That really should be computed from something as it would need changing based on the font -- probably based on `\baselineskip` (which is `12pt`), so not sure if it is just `1.5*\baselineskip`, or `\baselineskip + <some_lengths>` where `<some_lengths>` add up to `6pt`.

Answer (score 5):

I cannot give a better answer as Steven B. Segletes for adapting `mdframed`. But I can show an alternative using the `fitting` library of `tcolorbox` to create such boxes. The two major drawbacks are (1) it is not `mdframed` which was asked for, (2) the `fit` boxes are not breakable but they shrink their content if its getting too large (displayed in the exampled below). I can image that an unrestricted minimum height could be a future feature for `mdframed` and `tcolorbox`. Now, here is the alternative for the current moment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand*{\MinimumHeight}{5.0cm}%

\newtcolorbox{MyEnvironment}[1][]{%
  fit height from={\MinimumHeight} to {\textheight},
  enhanced,colback=yellow!25,colframe=black,colbacktitle=brown!25,
  coltitle=black,boxrule=0.4pt,titlerule=0pt,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,left=2.5mm,right=2.5mm,
  top=1mm,bottom=1mm,toptitle=1mm,bottomtitle=1mm,#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{MyEnvironment}[title={Short Title}]
    Some text for first paragraph.

    Some more text for other paragraphs.
\end{MyEnvironment}

\begin{MyEnvironment}[title={Some much longer title that takes up more than one line in the title frame}]
    Some text for first paragraph.
\end{MyEnvironment}

\begin{MyEnvironment}[title={Title of frame with much text}]
    \lipsum[1]
\end{MyEnvironment}

\begin{MyEnvironment}[title={Title of frame with too much text}]
    \lipsum[1-7]
\end{MyEnvironment}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the shrinked text on page two. This is an automated feature of the `fit` box which may or may not be of use for the intended application.

[image]