# Tikz:How to achieve the effect in the picture aesthetically?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, geometry, tikz-node, node-connections

**what i want to achieve：**

[image: what i want to achieve]

**my code：**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
        \draw (-1,0) rectangle (16,10);
        \draw (10,5) circle (5);
        \draw (5,5) circle (5);
        \node at (14,9.5) {$\Omega$};
        \linespread{1.5} % 
        \node at (2.5,5) {\shortstack{the day\\went out to\\an ice-cream, we said\\just let our silence melt\\the air as we walked across the\\our love never tiring}};
        \node at (12.5,5) {\shortstack{should\\talked it over but\\ever seems to get\\your fat head.You are too\\and l wish we had never met\\and l$^{,}$d married Tim instead}};
        \node at (7.5,5) {\shortstack{we\\have\\nothing\\in\\common}};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**The effect is unsatisfactory：**
[image: my code]

I hope that the picture can better grasp the relative distance and make the picture more beautiful.

Because this is a collection of poetry and mathematics, I hope that the corresponding structural features will be more obvious.

**thanks for your help！**

Comment: Welcome. // Thanks for the code. Unfortunately it won't compile: please add the missing lines. Thank you

Comment: @MS-SPO Thanks Reply! I have updated the code, this code can run directly on overleaf. It didn't work before probably because the content length exceeded the page width and the overall context was missing.

Comment: You could place each line separately or you could employ [parshapes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/450932) but that won't be very easier either with the degrees of freedom you have her.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with that. Aligning the text was the key. But I didn't manage to bend the alignment around the curves like you showed in the example.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
        \draw (-1,1) rectangle (16,9);
        \draw (11,5) ellipse (5 and 4);
        \draw (4,5) ellipse (5 and 4);
        \node at (15,8.5) {$\Omega$};
        \linespread{1.5} % 
        \node[align = right] at (3.4,5) {the day\\went out to\\an ice-cream, we said\\just let our silence melt\\the air as we walked across the\\our love never tiring};
        \node[align = left] at (11.6,5) {should\\talked it over but\\ever seems to get\\your fat head.You are too\\and l wish we had never met\\and l$^{,}$d married Tim instead};
        \node[align = center] at (7.5,5) {we\\have\\nothing\\in\\common};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]