# Left margin of table of contents in beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, margins

I'm making a presentation with the beamer class, and I use the theme Madrid (with default settings). After having completed some frames I noticed that the left margin of the contents page is much smaller then the margin of other pages. Also, since my section's names are quite short, this doesn't look very nice.

What I would like to do is increase the left margin of the contents page with, say, 1 cm.
This is what I tried first:

```
\begin{frame}{\contentsname}
   \setlength{\leftmargin}{2cm}
   \tableofcontents[pausesections]
\end{frame}
```

But apparently `\leftmargin` doesn't affect the table of contents. Also, playing around with `\setbeamersize{text margin left = 1cm}` influenced all frames, which is not what I'm looking for.

Next, I tried a trick described [here](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-chngmargonfly): creating a new environment in which the `\leftmargin` is changed.

```
\newenvironment{chg}{%
   \begin{list}{}{%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{1cm}%
   }%
\item[]}{\end{list}}

...

\begin{frame}{\contentsname}
   \begin{chg}
      \tableofcontents[pausesections]
   \end{chg}
\end{frame}
```

Strangely, this only influenced the titles of subsections, not those of the sections.

After having read some other similar questions I tried using minipages, like this:

```
\begin{frame}{\contentsname}
   \hspace*{1cm}
   \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
      \tableofcontents[pausesections]
   \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
```

This is getting closer: the left margin got larger but unfortunately the label separation between the content's titles was set to zero. Of course, I'd like to have the titles spread over the entire frame, as it had always been before introducing the minipage.

Any suggestions on how to fix the label separation in the table of contents, or other approaches to increase the left margin are welcome.

---

**Update:**

I just discovered that changing the heigt of the minipage might help. In [this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67284/fix-the-height-length-of-a-minipage) I found `\begin{minipage}[t][10cm][t]{\textwidth}` to replace `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}`. I tried this, changed some parameters and found out that `\begin{minipage}[c][6cm]{\textwidth}` works fine in my case. Obviously this '6cm' is just an estimate.

When I place an original version of the contents page next to this one, I see some more small transformations have been applied beside increasing the left margin. But as long as a more systematic solution doesn't show up, I'll keep this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked well for me (after figuring out the percentage of textwidth and textheight for parbox / minipage):

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{TOC}
\hfill
\parbox[t]{.95\textwidth}{
  \begin{minipage}[c][0.75\textheight]{\textwidth}
  \tableofcontents
  \end{minipage}
}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps a bit late, but I might need it some other time maybe.